# Binding variables to a superclass in PHP

Tags: php

So I have two classes:

**table.class**

```
<?php
    class table {
        protected $id = null;
        protected $table = null;

        function __construct() {

        }

        function bind($data) {
            // print_r($data);
            foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
               $this->key = $value;
               //   echo $key."--".$value;
               //     echo $this->$key;
            }
        }
   }
?>
```

**user.class**

```
<?php
    class user extends table
    {
        var $username = null;
        var $password = null;
        var $email = null;
        var $table = "user";
    }
?>
```

I also have an index bootstrap....

```
<?php
    include('table.class.php');
    include('user.class.php');

    $user = new user();
    $data = array("username" => "Forest", "password" => "*****",  "email"=>"foo@bar.com");    
    $user->bind($data);
    $classVars = get_class_vars(get_class($user));
    print_r($classVars);

?>
```

It SHOULD return:

```
Array(
    [username] => Forest,
    [password] => *******,
    [email]=>foo@bar.com
    [table] => user
)
```

INSTEAD it returns:

```
Array (
    [username] =>
    [password] =>
    [email] =>
    [table] => user

)
```

Can someone be kind enough to tell me why the variables are not binding to the superclass?????

According to here it should work:

http://codeslayer2010.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/developer-journal-2012-03-30-building-a-php-database-connection-class-from-scratch-singleton-activerecord/

Comment: I recommend quite strictly that you'll change your password ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `foreach` in `bind` you're using `$this->key = $value` instead of `$this->{$key} = $value`.

And to fetch variables of instance (not the class defaults) use [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php).

Answer (score 0):

> It SHOULD output:

No, it should not. `get_class_vars` returns variables as defined in class, you are looking for instantiated object properties, so you should use:

```
$objectVars = get_object_vars($user);
```